# Disparity Map obtained through StereoSGBM is flickering

Tags: python, opencv, depth, stereo-3d, color-depth

I am trying to implement stereo vision using 2 RPI v2 Cameras kept 8.43cm apart.
After performing camera calibration and rectification, I used StereoSGBM to compute disparity map.

But for some reason, the disparity map obtained is flickering too much.

Here is how it looks.  [disparity map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsRxL.png)

This is the left and right rectified image: [rectified image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2Jmz.png)

I made sure I cover every corner while calibrating.

I've tried same pipeline ( Different Parameter Value ) in gazebo and it works really well.

Here is how I am initiating the block Matcher.

```
    wsize = 15
    max_disp = 16*3
    sigma = 1.5
    lmbda = 8000.0

    block_size = 5
    min_disparity = 0
    num_disparities = 16
    uniqueness_ratio = 10
    speckle_window_size = 200
    speckle_range = 32
    disp_12_max_diff = 1
    pre_filter_cap = 63
    P1 = 8 * 3 * block_size * block_size
    P2 = 32 * 3 * block_size * block_size
    mode = cv2.StereoSGBM_MODE_SGBM_3WAY

    left_matcher = cv2.StereoSGBM_create(minDisparity=min_disparity,
                            numDisparities=num_disparities,
                            blockSize=block_size,
                            P1=P1,
                            P2=P2,
                            disp12MaxDiff=disp_12_max_diff,
                            preFilterCap=pre_filter_cap,
                            uniquenessRatio=uniqueness_ratio,
                            speckleWindowSize=speckle_window_size,
                            speckleRange=speckle_range,
                            mode=mode)

    right_matcher = cv2.ximgproc.createRightMatcher(left_matcher)
    wls_filter = cv2.ximgproc.createDisparityWLSFilter(left_matcher)
```

`            ret_val_l, left_image = left.read()
ret_val_r, right_image = right.read()

```
        if ret_val_r is None and ret_val_l is None:
            break


        R1, R2, P1, P2, Q, ROI1, ROI2  = cv2.stereoRectify(camera_matrix_1, distortion_coefficients_1, camera_matrix_2, distortion_coefficients_2, left_image.shape[:2], R, T)

        
        left_image_rect = np.zeros_like(left_image)
        x, y, w, h = ROI1
        left_image_rect[y:y+h, x:x+w] = left_image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        right_image_rect = np.zeros_like(right_image)
        x, y, w, h = ROI2
        right_image_rect[y:y+h, x:x+w] = right_image[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        left_image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(left_image_rect, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        right_image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(right_image_rect, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        left_disparity = left_matcher.compute(left_image_gray, right_image_gray)# .astype(np.float32)
        right_disparity = right_matcher.compute(right_image_gray, left_image_gray)# .astype(np.float32)

        wls_filter.setLambda(lmbda)
        wls_filter.setSigmaColor(sigma)  
        filtered_disp = wls_filter.filter(left_disparity, left_image_gray, disparity_map_right=right_disparity)

        jet_colormap = cv2.applyColorMap(filtered_disp.astype(np.uint8), cv2.COLORMAP_JET)`
```

I've tried with stereoBM, same issue. How do I make it consistent?

Comment: terrible picture. no texture on any of the surfaces. that'll give you terrible results. -- if you want people to reproduce your issue, you need to make it reproducible. [mre] that means *data*. screenshots are illustrations, not data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.